# How to preview and edit image using svg filter on my uploaded image?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, preview

Im going to make a simple application about uploading an image and then the image can edited by some filters. (in this case im using SVG filters)

```js
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('#pic').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
$("#uploadedPic").change(function() {
  readURL(this);
});

function function1() {
  document.getElementById('pic').style.cssText = "-webkit-filter: url('#normal')";
}

function function2() {
  document.getElementById('pic').style.cssText = "-webkit-filter: url('#f1')";
}

function function3() {
  document.getElementById('pic').style.cssText = "-webkit-filter: url('#f2')";
}

function function4() {
  document.getElementById('pic').style.cssText = "-webkit-filter: url('#f3')";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="all">
  <input type='file' id="uploadedPic" />
  <img id="pic" src="#" alt="your image" data-type="editable" />
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <defs>
      <filter id="normal" x="0" y="0">
      </filter>
      <filter id="f1" x="0" y="0">
        <feGaussianBlur in="A" stdDeviation="5"></feGaussianBlur>
      </filter>
      <filter id="f2" x="0" y="0">
        <feColorMatrix values="0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0
           0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0
           0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0
           0      0      0      1 0" /></feColorMatrix>
      </filter>
      <filter id="f3" x="0" y="0">
        <feConvolveMatrix filterRes="100 100" style="color-interpolation-filters:sRGB" order="3" kernelMatrix="0 -1 0    -1 4 -1   0 -1 0" preserveAlpha="true" /></feConvolveMatrix>
      </filter>
    </defs>
  </svg>
  <div id="btn">
    <button id="normal" onclick="function1()">normal</button>
    <button id="blur" onclick="function2()">blur</button>
    <button id="matrix" onclick="function3()">color matrix</button>
    <button id="cmatrix" onclick="function4()">convolve matrix</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

The Problem is that code isn't work well, i can edit the image but no image previewed. (notice : im using chrome, untested on firefox).
and I've test it in fiddle, the image was uploaded but the button filters not working. what is the problem?
So please, help me to fix that code and tell me where is the not correct code?

sorry for bad english. thankyou. hope someone help me.

Comment: Do you mean how to save the result? (it previews fine in Chrome Canary)

Comment: It works fine in Chrome 43 also.

Comment: @K3N i mean how to make preview works with filter, and how to save the result also?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau really? i using chrome 43 also. but not work. the image not previewing. but it works well in that code snippet. is there any problem with my browser?

Comment: The SVG filters only works with the element, not the bitmap of the canvas itself so they cannot be saved. There if a non-standard filter property on the context in Firefox that can be used, but it won't be reliable for public use. The only was as of now is to manually implement the filters using the ImageData object of the canvas, and apply it "manually".

Comment: @K3N thanks for advice k3n, but sorry I really don't understand how to implement filters to canvas use ImageData 'MANUALLY'. did you have any references for me so I can learn it?

Comment: @K3N I have an example, open this link http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/graphics/hands-on-css3/hands-on_svg-filter-effects.htm <<<< Im going to create simple app like that one.

Comment: @FachrizalAllolangi by "manually" I mean that you have to implement all the code to produce the effect iterating each pixel etc. If will of course be automatic in effect, but the browser will not automatically help out here. You have to see the SVG Filter specs to see how the formulas works etc, perhaps peek at the source code of Chromium/Firefox to see how they have implemented it. As you probably see now, it is not a straight forward task. If you are able to use Firefox only you *could* use its filter property on the context. Links coming...

Comment: [SVG Filters and formulas](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html#feBlendElement), [Firefox context.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/filter)